# Why is node-firebird giving a password error only when running many queries in succession?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, firebird

I am trying to run multiple queries in a row using [node-firebird](https://github.com/hgourvest/node-firebird), using Firebird 4.0 on Windows. In isql, I make a simple test database:

```
SQL> create database 'temp.fdb' page_size 8192 user SYSDBA password 'masterkey';
SQL> create table stuff( id int not null primary key, val int);
SQL> insert into stuff values(0, 0);
```

To simulate running multiple queries, I use a the following loop, based on an example from the node-firebird docs:

```js
var Firebird = require('node-firebird');

for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    console.log('running ' + i)
    var options = {};

    options.host = '127.0.0.1';
    options.port = 3050;
    options.database = <path to the database i just made>
    options.user = 'SYSDBA';
    options.password = 'masterkey';
    options.retryConnectionInterval = 1000; // reconnect interval in case of connection drop
    options.blobAsText = false; // set to true to get blob as text, only affects blob subtype 1

    Firebird.attach(options, function(err, db) {
        if (err)
            throw err;

        // db = DATABASE
        db.query('SELECT * FROM stuff', function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            // IMPORTANT: close the connection
            db.detach();
            console.log('connection closed: ' + i);
        });

    });
}
```

This runs as expected:

```
running 0
running 1
running 2
connection closed: 0
connection closed: 2
connection closed: 1
```

However, when I increase the number of iterations in the loop, it tells me the username and password are not defined:

```
running 0
running 1
running 2
running 3
running 4
running 5
running 6
running 7
running 8
running 9
C:<...>\node-firebird\lib\index.js:3454
        throw err;
        ^

Error: Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database
administrator to set up a Firebird login

    at doCallback (C:<...>\node_modules\node-firebird\lib\index.js:1360:21)
    at C:<...>\node_modules\node-firebird\lib\index.js:3138:21
    at loop (C:<...>\node_modules\node-firebird\lib\index.js:3198:29)
    at parseOpResponse (C:<...>\node_modules\node-firebird\lib\index.js:3481:29)
    at decodeResponse (C:<...>\node_modules\node-firebird\lib\index.js:3203:24)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:<...>\node_modules\node-firebird\lib\index.js:3115:13)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:512:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:343:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:316:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:253:10) {
  gdscode: 335544472,
  gdsparams: undefined
}

Node.js v20.4.0
```

This error confuses me, since the username and password works when I'm only running as few queries. How can I fix this so that I can run many queries in a row?

Comment: My first guess would be some sort of bug in node-firebird, which might cause it to produce a wrong error, or maybe authenticate incorrectly under load. Or it might be a bug in Firebird itself, that causes it to fail authentication under load. That said, if you need to perform multiple queries in a row, why are you not reusing the connection? Why are you closing the connection after each query?

Comment: In any case, you should report a bug to the node-firebird project, especially if you have a reproducible test case.